# Parsing BC Dates in d3 .v5 from csv file

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js

I converted a table from wikipedia displaying all wars in world history into a csv file, to build a scatter-plot out of these data.

**Formatting of CSV:**

```
War,Deathrange,Geometricmean(Note 1),Date,Combatants,Location,Notes
Conquests of Cyrus the Great,"100,000+","100,000",549 BC–530 BC,Persian Empire vs. various states,Middle East,"Number given is the sum of all deaths in battle recorded by writers during this time period, does not take into account civilian deaths, the actual number may be much greater."
Greco–Persian Wars,
```

I want to get the first date of "Date" – for example "549" – on the X-Axis. The radius of the dots should relate to the duration of the war.

**Issue**
I don't know how to parse "BC" dates in d.3

**So far I did:**
My approach is to find the numbers in the string with a Regex.

```
let dataset = await d3.csv("../wars.csv");
let dateNumber = dataset[0].Date.match(/\d+/g);
```

To check whether the date contains a "BC" and to convert it to "minus", I did:

```
 if (dataset[0].Date.includes("BC")) {
        const warStart = "-" + dateNumber[0];
        const warEnd = "-" + dateNumber[1];
        console.log(warStart + " and ends " + warEnd)

    }
```

**I have no idea, how to apply this approach on all dates – and not only [0]**.

I tried

```
 const dates = d => d.Date.match(/\d+/g);
    console.log(dates);
```

And console is logging:

```
function dates()
```

But no dates, even when indexing like "dates[1]"

**So how can I parse the dates containing "BC" in the CSV in a format, which enables d3 time-features to display them on the x-Axis?**

Because I am very new to JS and d3 I appreciate helpful ressources.

Best and thank you.

Comment: What do AD dates look like? Are they say "1066 AD"? In that case your regular expression needs to be something like `/\d{1,4} (AD|BC)/`.